# Finding the value of a constant k, such that the series satisfies a given number

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$
\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }3^{kn}=\frac{3}{2}
$$

The question asks to **find the value of the constant k such that** the above is satisfied.

Because there are only a few series from which we can find the sum using the various tests, I'm assuming it would be a geometric one.

And a geometric series sum is:
$$
\frac{a}{1-r}
$$

Now how to extend this to the question at hand, I'm not sure.

Comment: Your series is geometric. Express the ratio in terms of $k$.

Comment: Hint: $3^{kn}=(3^k)^n$.

Comment: Ah thanks. Trivial from here.